# Hyper-V Truecrypted Drive

Tags: truecrypt, hyper-v

I have been using my VM for a while and appreciated being able to script the machine startup in Powershell like so:

```
Start-VM -Name vmname
```

This allows me to just pop open an rdp window and avoid the Hyper-V Manager all together. But after installing TrueCrypt, I am forced to open the manager and open the virtual machine connection window to input the TrueCrypt drive decryption password before Windows boots up. Is there a way to script this out so that I can once again go from powershell script straight to rdp?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to automate entering the password.  But would require control of the desktop, which I dont believe meets your requirements.